# Instance variable creation in java

Tags: java, inheritance, hierarchy, instance-variables

If i have the following scenario:

```
public class Foo extends Baz{
  private String banana = "banana";
  //blah blah blah
}


public class Baz{
  protected static String apple = "apple"; 
}
```

Which get created first, apple or banana? I want to say apple gets created first, but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you mean `apple` to be a static variable rather than an instance variable, or not?

Comment: The specs are quite clear about this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`apple` is created first.  It is static, and in the parent level class.

The static initializer (which initializes the `apple` variable) will run as soon as the `Baz` class is loaded which will have to happen before an instance of `Baz` can be created.

The intsance initializer (which initializes the `banana` variable) will run as soon as an instance of `Foo` is created.

Answer (score 4):

`apple` is a *static* variable, so it's initialized at class initialization time. That occurs *before* an instances can be created - so it's initialized *before* `banana` in this particular case.

If `apple` were an *instance* variable, it would still be initialized before `banana`: instance variables are initialized as if the initializers occur at the start of the constructor body, but *after* any chaining to a superclass constructor. (In case you're interested, this is different to C#, where the instance variable initializers are executed *before* constructor chaining.)

Answer (score 2):

To create an instance of a class, you need this class to be loaded and initialized, so obviously, the static fields will be initialized before the first instance field can be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, `apple` is created first and then `banana` is created. You can read why this occurs in the [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), [Chapter 12. Execution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html):

- [12.2. Loading of Classes and Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2)
- [12.5. Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

Answer (score 0):

You have given clearly `Baz` is the parent class and `Foo` is extending `Baz`. So when ever the class initialized the parent class variables will initialize. That too the `apple` is static variable.

When ever the Static varibles will be initialized before the instance varibles. If those are not initialized it will take as default value for int as '0'.